# Where are the barrel roll locations in Season 2 Alps Classic?

Tags: asphalt-8

I am trying to get the last star on the Alps Classic map of Season 2 which requires me to perform 3 barrel rolls in a single game.

However, I am having difficulty finding the 3 spots required for me to perform the rolls. Where can they be found and are there any tips in completing the challenge?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 when you stay to the right at the beginning of the level. The last is after you go through the tunnels on the left.  Be sure to stay left and the ramp is on the left before the finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do a barrel roll off a regular ramp if you hit it mostly off center (more towards the tire than the center of the car).  That's how I just did it using the Audi R8 e-tron.  I hit the first ramp that way.